# Regular Expression for word contained in a predefined set of words

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, cpu-word

I have a pre-defined set of words like
Horse Pearl House

And I would want my regular expression to match any word contained among those 3.

Example: orse - contained in Horse. 
Pea - contained in Pearl. 
Ho - contained in Horse and House.

How do I create a regular expression to achieve this in JavaScript or c#?

I was thinking in this direction.

```
\b*(Horse|Pearl|House)
```

Comment: do you also want to get the match words?

Comment: Yes indeed part the word or the whole word needs to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = ["Horse", "Pearl", "House"];
var string_matched="";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if (/se/gi.test(arr[i])) {

        string_matched += ", " + arr[i];
    }
}
```

You will get the matched strings in the **string_matched** variable.

Comment: /se/ is the word or letter that you want to search in the provided words i.e Horse, Pearl, House. You can make it dynamic.

Comment: So in the above code only The word "se" is matched against horse,Pearl,House ? how do I get any word to dynamically match ?

Comment: Say the user inputs se or ho or pe or earl it needs to match

Comment: then your expression will become /se/gi or /ho/gi or /pe/gi or /earl/gi .